# How to publish expo app as update of a native app

Tags: ios, react-native

I’m new using react native. I developed an app with it and now I have to publish it but as an update of a current app that was previously developed in native for both ios and android.

The idea is to publish it in both stores to replace the existing ones and then users will see the new app as an update, not a new installation.

I have the credentials for both stores and everyting to publish the app. The only thing is to publish it as an update of the current version

Can anybody give me some tips to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`iOS`

a) Use same bundle identifier that available in store

b) Create provision profile for dev and app store

c) Upload new build

then it would it as update of existing store app

`Android`

a) Use same package name

b) While taking build same keystore that used for existing store app

c) Upload new build

Answer (score 0):

Yes just build the bundler for android and ios but make sure that

In Android, package name(application ID) should be same for different versions of app binary. Also signing certificate remain same during version change.

In iOS, Bundle ID must be same for different versions/builds of app binary. Apart from this, provisional profiles and certificates also need to be same.

You can also use [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) for your app CI/CD process

given on [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986098/migrating-from-hybrid-app-to-native-app-at-later-point-of-time)

Answer (score 0):

How to change existing expo project id

enter this command in the terminal

```
eas init --id your_projectId_here
```

project id can be found in your expo account.

it will ask y/n.
hit y